# Achieving multiple inheritance using python dataclasses

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, mixins, python-dataclasses, method-resolution-order

I'm trying to use the new python dataclasses to create some mix-in classes (already as I write this I think it sounds like a rash idea), and I'm having some issues. Behold the example below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class NamedObj:
    name: str
            
    def __post_init__(self):
        print("NamedObj __post_init__")
        self.name = "Name: " + self.name
    
@dataclass
class NumberedObj:
    number: int = 0
        
    def __post_init__(self):
        print("NumberedObj __post_init__")
        self.number += 1
    
@dataclass
class NamedAndNumbered(NumberedObj, NamedObj):
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NamedAndNumbered __post_init__")
```

If I then try:

```
nandn = NamedAndNumbered('n_and_n')
print(nandn.name)
print(nandn.number)
```

I get

```py
NumberedObj __post_init__
NamedAndNumbered __post_init__
n_and_n
1
```

Suggesting it has run `__post_init__` for `NamedObj`, but not for `NumberedObj`.
What I would like is to have NamedAndNumbered run `__post_init__` for both of its mix-in classes, Named and Numbered. One might think that it could be done if `NamedAndNumbered` had a `__post_init__` like this:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    super(NamedObj, self).__post_init__()
    super(NumberedObj, self).__post_init__()
    print("NamedAndNumbered __post_init__")
```

But this just gives me an error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__post_init__'` when I try to call `NamedObj.__post_init__()`.

At this point I'm not entirely sure if this is a bug/feature with dataclasses or something to do with my probably-flawed understanding of Python's approach to inheritance. Could anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    super(NamedObj, self).__post_init__()
    super(NumberedObj, self).__post_init__()
    print("NamedAndNumbered __post_init__")
```

doesn't do what you think it does. `super(cls, obj)` will return a proxy to the class **after** `cls` in `type(obj).__mro__` - so, in your case, to `object`. And the whole point of cooperative `super()` calls is to avoid having to explicitely call each of the parents.

The way cooperative `super()` calls are intended to work is, well, by being "cooperative" - IOW, everyone in the mro is supposed to relay the call to the next class (actually, the `super` name is a rather sad choice, as it's not about calling "the super class", but about "calling the next class in the mro").

IOW, you want each of your "composable" dataclasses (which are not mixins - mixins only have behaviour) to relay the call, so you can compose them in any order. A first naive implementation would look like:

```
@dataclass
class NamedObj:
    name: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NamedObj __post_init__")
        self.name = "Name: " + self.name

@dataclass
class NumberedObj:
    number: int = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NumberedObj __post_init__")
        self.number += 1

@dataclass
class NamedAndNumbered(NumberedObj, NamedObj):

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NamedAndNumbered __post_init__")
```

BUT this doesn't work, since for the last class in the mro (here `NamedObj`), the next class in the mro is the builtin `object` class, which doesn't have a `__post_init__` method. The solution is simple: just add a base class that defines this method as a noop, and make all your composable dataclasses inherit from it:

```
class Base(object):
    def __post_init__(self):
        # just intercept the __post_init__ calls so they
        # aren't relayed to `object`
        pass

@dataclass
class NamedObj(Base):
    name: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NamedObj __post_init__")
        self.name = "Name: " + self.name

@dataclass
class NumberedObj(Base):
    number: int = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NumberedObj __post_init__")
        self.number += 1

@dataclass
class NamedAndNumbered(NumberedObj, NamedObj):

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NamedAndNumbered __post_init__")
```

Comment: thanks, this is a great answer. If there's some dependency between these composable classes, would it make sense to have the following policy:
1. Have the first one you want executed last on the list in the child class statement (obviously)
2. Put the `super().__post_init__()` in each of their `__post_init__` definitions at the end, rather than the beginning of the `__post_init__` definition?

Comment: Also, is it fair to say that this is something of a flaw with dataclasses? With normal classes you can just put `super().__init__()` in any class without having to worry about object not having that method. You might think that the base object for dataclasses should have a noop `__post_init__` like you created above.

Comment: Just want to say thank you! This saved me a lot of time!!!!

Answer (score 6):

The problem (most probably) isn't related to `dataclass`es. The problem is in Python's [method resolution](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html). Calling method on `super()` invokes the first found method from parent class in the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) chain. So to make it work you need to call the methods of parent classes manually:

```
@dataclass
class NamedAndNumbered(NumberedObj, NamedObj):

    def __post_init__(self):
        NamedObj.__post_init__(self)
        NumberedObj.__post_init__(self)
        print("NamedAndNumbered __post_init__")
```

Another approach (if you really like `super()`) could be to continue the MRO chain by calling `super()` in all parent classes (but it needs to have a `__post_init__` in the chain):

```
@dataclass
class MixinObj:
    def __post_init__(self):
        pass

@dataclass
class NamedObj(MixinObj):
    name: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NamedObj __post_init__")
        self.name = "Name: " + self.name

@dataclass
class NumberedObj(MixinObj):
    number: int = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NumberedObj __post_init__")
        self.number += 1

@dataclass
class NamedAndNumbered(NumberedObj, NamedObj):

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NamedAndNumbered __post_init__")
```

In both approaches:

```
>>> nandn = NamedAndNumbered('n_and_n')
NamedObj __post_init__
NumberedObj __post_init__
NamedAndNumbered __post_init__
>>> print(nandn.name)
Name: n_and_n
>>> print(nandn.number)
1
```

Comment: Now that's better... But the base class doesn't have to be a dataclass.

Comment: "Another approach (if you really like super())" => cooperative super calls are the prefered way to call on the parent class, unless you have a serious technical reason to avoid them and harcode the call instead. And in this case, they __really__ are the best solution, as they let you combine the various "not-really-mixin" classes in any order without having to hardcode anything, AND they will properly handle diamond heritage.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
`NamedObj` is last in line and does not inherit from anything in the inherit hierarchy.

```py
@dataclass
class NamedObj:
    name: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        print("NamedObj __post_init__")
        self.name = "Name: " + self.name

@dataclass
class NumberedObj:
    number: int = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NumberedObj __post_init__")
        self.number += 1

@dataclass
class NamedAndNumbered(NumberedObj, NamedObj):

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        print("NamedAndNumbered __post_init__")
```