# __post_init__() for multiple inherited dataclasses

Tags: python-3.x, constructor, multiple-inheritance, python-dataclasses

Trying to evaluate if dataclasses are suitable for an upcoming project, but right now I'm stuck with this code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MixinA:
    attrA: int
    def __post_init__(self):
        print('MixinA post_init')
        self.attrA = [self.attrA]

@dataclass
class MixinB:
    attrB: str
    def __post_init__(self):
        print('MixinB post_init')
        self.attrB = [self.attrB]

@dataclass
class MixinC:
    attrC: bool
    def __post_init__(self):
        print('MixinC post_init')
        self.attrC = [self.attrC]

@dataclass
class Inherited(MixinC, MixinB, MixinA):
    pass

obj = Inherited(4, 'Hello', False)
print(obj.attrA, obj.attrB, obj.attrC)
print(obj.__class__.mro())
```

It is a surprise to me that only `__post_init__()` in the first base class is called, when I expect all three are invoked:

```
MixinC post_init
4 Hello [False]
[<class '__main__.Inherited'>, <class '__main__.MixinC'>, <class '__main__.MixinB'>, <class '__main__.MixinA'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Besides, changing inheritance doesn't do me any good. Following inheritance generates the exact same output as above:

```py
class MixinA:
class MixinB(MixinA):
class MixinC(MixinB):
class Inherited(MixinC):
```

Did I write the testing code in a wrong way, or is current behavior done by oversight or intention?

The core issue for me is, I want to transform each attribute before generating the final dataclass instances. The actual inheritance is of larger scale, and doing it within each and every class would be *very* redundant.

If `__post_init__()` is a no-go, is there any alternative approach (such as `InitVar` or custom `__init__()`)?

Comment: 1. You specify one type in the annotation but keep the other. That's not right.
2. Using mixins you create a class with one method __post_init__. This is why it is the only method called.

Comment: I would advise you to do the conversion to a list when reading from a dataclass in your code.

Comment: 1. Yep, I'm aware it wasn't correct. Actually I want to only convert the type if it isn't already a list, so should have been Union[<type>, List[<type>]] instead. Just laziness when posting question. 2. Now I understand why this approach is not working, thx.

Comment: Seems this question can be marked as dup, I found what I needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59986413

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Achieving multiple inheritance using python dataclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986413/achieving-multiple-inheritance-using-python-dataclasses)

Comment: @MateusTerra Indeed, it's the same link I just added in comment :) I end up using `__post_init__` chaining.