# dataclass __annotation__ not working with inheritance

Tags: python, dictionary, object, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I tried this code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Data1:
    d11: str
    d12: float

@dataclass
class Data2:
    d21: str
    d22: float

@dataclass
class D3(Data1, Data2): pass

print(D3.__annotations__)
```

But the annotations for `D3` are only `{'d11': <class 'str'>, 'd12': <class 'float'>}`. Why does it not include annotations for the `Data2` fields?

Comment: I guess this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986413/. Anyway, it certainly does "inherit" from both bases (you'll notice, for example, that if you actually try to create a `D3`, you'll be expected to provide all four field values, and the result will store them). It's only the *annotations* that are limited in this way.

Comment: I got the same result on Python3.8, 3.9, but an empty `{}` on Python3.10, 3.11.

Comment: Whoever voted to close as not reproducible: what? Did you try it?

Comment: The annotations are literally that: what has been annotated. You are likely looking for the fields instead.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is due to a bug fixed in Python 3.10.

Comment: Is this just a philosophical "why" question, or do you have a problem you are trying to solve? A "why" question is opinion based and off topic here, but for an actual programming question, solutions could be found.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I would expect the derived class to reflect both sets of annotations, because they annotate the fields and derived instances will have those fields. Wouldn't type-checkers depend on that?

Comment: @zvone I may have over-interpreted the title when editing the question for clarity. It could be that OP actually figured this meant that the inheritance was not working right at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Type checkers need to be aware of inheritance anyway (e.g. for methods and properties) plus they cannot use `__annotations__` in the first place (since type checking is static). For runtime type inspection, per-class `__annotations__` offer more information and usually more relevant ones (since you e.g. just need to add properties for new fields/annotations in the first place).

Comment: What **does** use `__annotations__`, then? Documentation generators? What's the point of saving that metadata if it doesn't help Mypy and doesn't affect ordinary runtime behaviour?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Runtime inspection as for Dataclasses and NamedTuple, for one. Similar libraries such as attrs or pydantic as well. I’ve also used it for deserialisation personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__annotations__` is for the literal annotations in the `class` body.  It is not intended to represent inheritance at all.
If, for example, `D3` actually has annotations only these are visible:

```
@dataclass
class D3(Data1, Data2):
    a: 3

print(D3.__annotations__)  # {'a': 3}
```

Note that the "inherited annotations" are available via [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints), which achieves this by "merging all the `__annotations__` along `C.__mro__` in reverse order". For dataclasses, [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) also provides the full `Field` specifications for a class or instance.

---

In your specific case, the `__annotations__` are non-empty due to [a bug fixed in Python 3.10](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/99535). Prior to Python 3.10, `__annotations__` is only created when there actually are annotations; this means that if a parent class has annotations but a child class does not, the parent annotations are visible via the usual attribute lookup.

Accessing the actual `class`' annotation, i.e. circumventing parent attribute lookup

```
@dataclass
class D3(Data1, Data2):
    pass

print(D3.__dict__["__annotations__"])
```

will trigger `KeyError: '__annotations__'` in Python 3.9 or earlier, and print `{}` in Python 3.10 or later.

Comment: `get_type_hints` does not seem to be working.