# Python get_type_hints not returning parent's annotations of child dataclass

Tags: python-3.x, annotations, python-dataclasses

I want to get all fields of a inherited dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import get_type_hints

@dataclass
class A:
  a: int = 0

@dataclass
class B(A):
  b: int = 0


a = A(a=4)
b = B(a=4, b=5)
print(a.__annotations__)
print(b.__annotations__)
```

As already in other posts this will print:

```
{'a': <class 'int'>}
{'b': <class 'int'>}
```

Some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76026531/1714692), suggest the usage of `get_type_hints`. But in my case doing:

```
print(get_type_hints(a))
print(get_type_hints(b))
```

which prints

```
{'a': <class 'int'>}
{'b': <class 'int'>}
```

Whereas I would have expected something like `{'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'int'>}` in the second print.

Is this correct? Am I doing something wrong?
The only way I could extract parent's fields is the following:

```
print([el.name for el in fields(b)])
```

Is this the only way?